# Find names with Regular Expression

Tags: regex

For finding names in a big text I have the following regex

```
([A-Z][a-z]*)[\s-]([A-Z][a-z]*)
```

This works fine for normals names like "Jack Oneill" or "John Guidetti". But there are a few possibilities that I want to find, but cannot find. Like:

```
Chandler Murial Bing
Gandalf the Gray
Pieter van den Woude
```

I cannot seem to get this right with my limited knowledge of Regular Expressions. Can anyone help me (and please provide a good website/book for this) :)

Comment: First you have to know your definition of a "name" and after that it might not be impossible to solve with a regular expression but it could be.

Comment: My definition of "name" is two words behind each other starting with capital letters. Or sometimes 3 words. And some times 1 wordt with capital letter, 1 or 2 words without, and then 1 word with.

Comment: And i know it's not the true defenition of name, but I am going to use this to easely find "names" and then select the ones I need :)

Comment: There's an elephant in the room. "Elaine kicked Kramer in the butt." It seems your definition just created a new character in Seinfeld.

Comment: `And i know it's not the true defenition of name` - no, because there isn't one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way to approach a regular expression problem is to describe the matches you are looking for (usually called *grammar*).

For example, from your question, I might describe it like the following:

6. A **capitalized word** is defined as one capital letter and 1+ letters/dashes or one capital letter and a `.` (an initial).
7. An **uncapitalized word** is defined as 1 letter and 1+ letters/dashes (not perfect, because that could allow ending in a dash).
8. First word starts with a capital letter
9. Last word ends with a capital letter
10. 0+ capitalized words between first and last word
11. *Then* 0-2 uncapitalized words between first capitalized words and last word
12. At least two words.
13. Words are broken by whitespace

If this provides a reasonably close match to the desired result set (and to be clear, for names, there are so many variations that you will either have false positives or false negatives), then you begin constructing the expression:

1. Capitalized word: `[A-Z]([a-z]+|\.)`
2. Uncapitalized word: `[a-z][a-z\-]+`

Result:

```
 [A-Z]([a-z]+|\.)(?:\s+[A-Z]([a-z]+|\.))*(?:\s+[a-z][a-z\-]+){0,2}\s+[A-Z]([a-z]+|\.)
```

Matches (in bold):

> Hello my name is **Chandler Muriel Bing**.  I have a friend who is named **Pieter van den Woude** and he has another friend, **A. A. Milne**. **Gandalf the Gray** joins us. Together, we make up the **Friends Cast and Crew**.

Problems:

- Because you want to match **Gandalf the Gray** and **Pieter van den Woude** you will inevitably match other sets that consist of names with uncapitalized words in between (Friends Cast and Crew).  The above grammar attempts to limit the problem by limiting it to **2** uncapitalized words.  You could also create a set of **allowed uncapitalized words** instead ("van", "der", "the"), and only match those words.
- Doesn't allow for non-Latin-alphabet letters, ligatures, [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic), etc.
- As I and others have pointed out, regular expressions will never be perfect for this situation, but as you said, you want something to get you most of the way there.  In this case, the above expression should do a pretty good job, but consider it a **blunt instrument**! You've been warned.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, just add another

```
[\s-]([A-Z][a-z]*)
```

Generally speaking, regex is not suitable for this problem, there are too many special cases, you will need to build a list of those names.

For complex names, you may refer to [natural language processing]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing