# Remove dynamic time and name combinations using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am unsuccessfully trying to use regex to remove time stamps and names from the online conversations I am processing.

The pattern I am trying to remove looks like this: `[08:03:16] Name:`

It is randomly distributed throughout the conversation instances.

The `Name` portion of the pattern can be lower or uppercase and can contain multiple names, e.g. `Dave`, `adam Jons`, `Wei-Xing`.

I am using the following regex:

`[A-Z]([a-z]+|\.)(?:\s+[A-Z]([a-z]+|\.))*(?:\s+[a-z][a-z\-]+){0,2}\s+[A-Z]([a-z]+|\.)`

From [Find names with Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653942/find-names-with-regular-expression), but this only removes names outside the timestamp example provided above (and only works for some names in the timestamps).

I have been looking through SO for a while now to find something that might help me but nothing has worked across all examples so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks a lot more complicated than it has to be - might be easier to match the timestamp format, then match characters up until the next `:` is found (assuming that names can't have `:`s in them):

```
\[(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\] [^:]+:
```

https://regex101.com/r/5i4HId/1